# Center an image in a div with text on the right

Tags: javascript, css, html

How can I center an image withing a div what has text on the right hand side.
The page is percentage based and I want the image dead center and the text floated to the right.

Here is what I have so far

```css
IMG.logo {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto }
```

```html
<div id="logoDiv">
   <p class="bold marginleft5 floatright paddingtop60">Logout</p><p class="floatright paddingtop60">Hello Bill</p>
   <img alt="Logo" src="~/Content/Images/logo.png" class="logo" height="80" width="245" />
</div>
```

I know that I can take the text out to the next line then the logo will be dead center but is it possible to have it on the same line as the image?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```css
IMG.logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

Check it out here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lcza8f6r/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could mock floating by using absolute positioning by zeroing out the top and right.

```css
img.logo {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.floatright {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 400px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    text-align:right;
}
.line1 {
    top: 0px;
}
.line2 {
    top: 16px;
}
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo-div">
    <p class="bold floatright line1">Logout</p>
    <p class="floatright line2">Hello Bill</p>
    <img alt="Britannia Logo" src="~/Content/Images/logo.png"
        class="logo" height="80" width="245" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that will work on wide and narrow screens: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/vmwgk

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.logoDiv {
    width: 100%;
}

.logo {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
}

.text {
    width: calc(50% - 130px); 
    float: right;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="logoDiv">
    <div class="text">
      <p>Logout</p>
      <p>Hello Bill</p>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
       <img alt="Britannia Logo" src="http://placehold.it/245x80" height="80" width="245">
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```